# Strategies for testing multi-user desktop application

Tags: testing

We are developing a multi-user desktop application with C# 3.5, windows forms and sql 2008.
There are various things I want to test -
1) performance - how application behaves when multiple users are accessing the database?
2) How to simulate a conflict, and test how application is helping out the user.
How can I test the above scenarios?

Any other scenarios you can think of?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

We need to see how the application communicates with DB layer

- Web Services or stored procedure calls
- For Stored proceduress I would suggest using SQLQueryStress - sql server query performance testing tool
- Alternatively if it through web services I would suggest testing using VSTT
- VSTT has good information and articles on web testing, load testing
- Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide (Version 2.0) Published http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edglas/archive/2010/04/13/visual-studio-performance-testing-quick-reference-guide-version-2-0-published.aspx

One more alternate option is

- SQL 2008 has data services - Exposing Stored procedures as Web Services
- You can exposre core procedures and load test them as web services in VSTT